# CoffeeScript function argument

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a function that I want to pass an argument, market, to the function freeSample, but I can't seem to get it set as an argument. Please take a moment to look at my code and help me to understand how to get the market as an argument in the freeSample function.

```
(freeSample) ->  
 market = $('#market')
  jQuery('#dialog-add').dialog =
   resizable: false
   height: 175
   modal: true
   buttons: ->
    'This is Correct': ->
      jQuery(@).dialog 'close'
    'Wrong Market': ->
      market.focus()
      market.addClass 'color'
      jQuery(@).dialog 'close'
```

UPDATE: Here is the JavaScript I currently have that I am trying to convert to CoffeeScript.

```
function freeSample(market) 
 {
   var market = $('#market');
   jQuery("#dialog-add").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:175,
    modal: true,
     buttons: {
      'This is Correct': function() {
         jQuery(this).dialog('close');
     },
      'Wrong Market': function() {
        market.focus();
        market.addClass('color');
        jQuery(this).dialog('close');
     }
    }
  });
 }
```

Comment: Can you also provide your JS code please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you have here is not a function named `freeSample`. Is an anonymous function with a single argument called `freeSample`. The syntax for functions in CoffeeScript is like this:

```
myFunctionName = (myArgument, myOtherArgument) ->
```

So in your case it could be something like this:

```
freeSample = (market) ->
  #Whatever
```

**EDIT** (after OP updated the question):
In your specific case you could do it like so:

```
freeSample = (market) ->
  market = $("#market")
  jQuery("#dialog-add").dialog
    resizable: false
    height: 175
    modal: true
    buttons:
      "This is Correct": ->
        jQuery(this).dialog "close"

      "Wrong Market": ->
        market.focus()
        market.addClass "color"
        jQuery(this).dialog "close"
```

PS. There is an (awesome) online tool for converting between js/coffeescript and can be found here: http://js2coffee.org/

The above snippet generated by this tool.